# Alternative to ur_description on ros-melodic?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am running ubuntu 18.04 with ros-melodic
When I am trying to run an old code I get an error saying ur_description was not found.
when I went to the documentation on [roswiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ur_description) I think that ur_description was available only till ros-kinetic.

So is there any alternative that will work the same in ros-melodic?

```
sushilsundaram@cmu:~/Documents/ros_course/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_support/urdf$ rosrun xacro xacro hrwros.xacro > hrwros.urdf 
resource not found: ur_description
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/sushilsundaram/Documents/ros_course/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros/hrwros_msgs
ROS path [2]=/home/sushilsundaram/Documents/ros_course/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_support
ROS path [3]=/home/sushilsundaram/Documents/ros_course/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros/hrwros_utilities
ROS path [4]=/home/sushilsundaram/Documents/ros_course/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros/hrwros_week1
ROS path [5]=/home/sushilsundaram/Documents/ros_course/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_week2
ROS path [6]=/home/sushilsundaram/Documents/ros_course/hrwros_ws/src/urdf_tutorial
ROS path [7]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
```

---

Edit: Hey, Thanks for the reply and the help.

```
sushilsundaram@cmu:~/Documents/ros_course/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_support/urdf$ rosdep check -i --from-paths $HOME/Documents/ros_course/hrwros_ws/src
All system dependencies have been satisfied
ERROR[hrwros_support]: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [turtlebot_description]
    rosdep key : turtlebot_description
    OS name    : ubuntu
    OS version : bionic
    Data: <no data>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317606/alternative-to-ur_description-on-ros-melodic?/) by [sushil.sundaram](https://answers.ros.org/users/31419/sushil.sundaram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-03-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
Please don't post updates as answers. They're not answers.

Edit your original question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So is there any alternative that will work the same in ros-melodic?

You can still build `universal_robot` on Melodic in a Catkin workspace.

See #q252478 for the general procedure (but of course use `melodic` instead of `kinetic`).

---

Edit:

> ```
> sushilsundaram@cmu:~/Documents/ros_course/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_support/urdf$ rosdep check -i --from-paths $HOME/Documents/ros_course/hrwros_ws/src
> ```

```
All system dependencies have been satisfied
ERROR[hrwros_support]: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [turtlebot_description]
    rosdep key : turtlebot_description
    OS name    : ubuntu
    OS version : bionic
    Data: <no data>
```

This would seem to be only one dependency (instead of "far too many").

The problem here is that `hrwros_support` depends on `turtlebot_description` which hasn't been released into Melodic yet.

It has only very few dependencies (looking at the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_description)), so you could try adding `turtlebot_description` (together with its dependencies) in your workspace and fulfill the dependency requirements that way.

Do note though: as far as I know, the packages in HRWROS were specifically created for Kinetic, so the problems that you're running into getting this to work on Melodic are somewhat expected. There is also no guarantee that after you get your workspace to build, the whole setup will actually work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sushil.sundaram](https://answers.ros.org/users/31419/sushil.sundaram/) on 2019-03-05**:
Hey
Thanks for the reply. The issue with this method is there are far too many dependencies that haven't been ported.
If there is no other alternative then I'll just have to do it this way.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
Your comment surprises me, because I build the entire set of `universal_robot` packages on Melodic just about every week.

If you can show what the output of

```
rosdep check -i --from-paths $HOME/Documents/ros_course/hrwros_ws/src
```

is, perhaps we can see what the problem is.

**Comment by [sushil.sundaram](https://answers.ros.org/users/31419/sushil.sundaram/) on 2019-03-06**:
I just figured out that it wasn't the problem with the universal_robot clone having issues it was a problem with my urdf needing more dependencies.
Thanks a lot for all the help.

**Comment by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) on 2020-02-20**:
What dependencies were you missing? Can you elaborate on how you solved your issue?